# Trying to import a class found in a JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I have built a simple project called LibTest that has one class with the following code:

```
    public class MainTest
    {
        public static tclass l;
    }
```

In secondary simple project I have the defined class tclass:

```
    public class tclass
    {
        int i;
    }
```

Then I export tclass to a JAR file. At LibTest->Properties->BuildPath I click on AddExternalJar and select tclass.jar ( I also tried checking the JAR at Order and Export) but I still get an error at MainTest "tclass cannot be resolved to a type".

I don't see what is missing.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: can we see your code that is importing tclass

Comment: i do not import by code. I did it via the Project->properties->buildPath-AddExternalJar

Comment: Solved by checking also "export generated class files and resources" when exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After including your jar file, you also need to import your class using its full path in your MainTest class. e.g:

```
import com.package.tclass;
```

Comment: I would like to send 3rd parties only the JAR so I am not sure they will be able to do so.